# Object.const_get and Rails - cutting off parent module names

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following code to pull out and instantiate Rails controllers:

```
def get_controller(route)
  name = route.requirements[:controller]
  return if name.nil?


  if name.match(/\//)
    controller_name = name.split('/').map(&:camelize).join('::')
  else
    controller_name = name.camelize
  end

  p controller_name: controller_name

  controller = Object.const_get("#{controller_name}Controller")

  p controller: controller
  controller.new
end
```

some routes are single names - "users", "friends", "neighbors", "politicians", etc...

other routes are nested, such as "admin/pets", "admin/shopping_lists", "admin/users", etc...

The above code works (in that it properly builds and instantiates the controller) in most of the cases mentioned, except for one - in this example, "admin/users"

from the `puts` statements, I'm getting the following:

```
{:controller_name=>"Admin::Users"}
{:controller => UsersController}
```

You'll notice that the namespace `Admin` is getting cut off.  My guess is that since this is only the case for controllers which share a name in multiple namespaces (`users` and `admin/users`), it has something do to with Rails autoloading (?).  Any idea about what is causing this?

As per the comment from lx00st, I should also point out that I've tried various forms of getting these constants, another attempt was as follows:

```
sections = name.split('/')
sections.map(&:camelize).inject(Object) do |obj, const|
  const += "Controller" if const == sections.last
  obj.const_get(const)
end
```

The same problem was encountered with this approach.

Comment: In this case `const_get` looks for a constant in `Object` module. You should end with something that call  `Admin.const_get("UsersController")`

Comment: I tried that as well - I'll add that to the OP

Comment: And if this called directly from rails console? `Admin.const_get("UsersController")`

Comment: and tell your ruby version

Comment: No offence to the design approach you have selected... I just wonder how efficient it is (it might be expensive for go through these lookups for every request), as well if the approach itself could handle name-spacing.

Comment: @Myst, i agree, it's only for testing purposes, so efficiency doesn't matter so much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was solved by an answer from user apneadiving which can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29920332/2128691)

> Be aware that there are vicious cases in Rails development mode. In order to gain speed, the strict minimum is loaded. Then Rails looks for classes definitions when needed.
>
> But this sometimes fails big time example, when you have say `::User` already loaded, and then look for `::Admin::User`. Rails would not look for it, it will think `::User` does the trick.
>
> This can be solved using `require_dependency` statements in your code.

Personally I think this is a bug, not a feature, but...so it goes.  It solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, this code is superfluous:

```
if name.match(/\//)
  controller_name = name.split('/').map(&:camelize).join('::')
else
  controller_name = name.camelize
end
```

The only string would perfectly handle both cases:

```
controller_name = name.split('/').map(&:camelize).join('::')
```

Then, you probably want to handle namespaces properly:

```
n_k = controller_name.split('::')
klazz = n_k.last

namespace_object = if n_k.length == 1
                     Object
                   else
                     Kernel.const_get(n_k[0..-2].join('::'))
                   end

controller = namespace_object.const_get("#{klazz}Controller")
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: you're right about the top code being superfluous, thank you for that.  At the bottom, calling `get_const` on `Kernel` gives me an undefined method error.  What do you mean by handling the namespaces properly?

Comment: That did not even what? The code above works for me pretty fine.

Comment: Sorry, I meant that I should have realized that `get_const` is not a method, but since it was the end of the week my brain had stopped working :p

Comment: That code does definitely work, but it doesn't solve my problem - the interpreter is still just ignoring the "Admin" namespace.  If I change the name of the namespaced controller - for example, 'AdminUsers' - then it is recognized - but that's going too far in my opinion.  What's the point of namespaces if Rails ignores them?

Comment: in fact, this is solved by an answer apneadiving gives [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29920332/2128691)

Comment: `require_dependency`, yes. sigh. rails. sigh.