# Ruby namespacing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, namespaces

I'm pretty new to ruby, coming from a php background, but something is not clicking with me.

So, let's say I have a Ruby on Rails application and I am versioning my API like so:

```
app
|_controllers
  |_api
  | |_v1
  | | |_application_controller.rb
  | | |_user_controller.rb
  | |_application_controller.rb
  |_application_controller.rb
```

With the class structure with

```rb
# Versioned API V1 app controller
module Api
  module V1
    class ApplicationController
    end
  end
end

# Versioned API app controller
module Api
  class ApplicationController
  end
end

# Root app controller
class ApplicationController
end

#The code in question
module Api
  module V1
    class UserController < ApplicationController
    end
  end
end
```

So the question is, does ruby look for `Api::V1::ApplicationController`, `Api::ApplicationController`, or `ApllicationController` for extending?

Does the `< ApplicationController` look for it's own namespace unless I specify `Api::ApplicationController`? If so, how do I specify the root one?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

When you use

```
#The code in question
module Api
  module V1
    class UserController < ApplicationController
    end
  end
end
```

`ApplicationController`definition will be searched in `Api::V1` then if not found in `Api` then if not found in the root namespace.

I agree it could be confusing, that's why I tend to use absolute paths like so: `::ApplicationController`

If ever I'd need `Api::ApplicationController`, I'd write `::Api::ApplicationController`

Basically the `::` tells ruby to start from the root namespace and not from where the code lives.

---

***Sidenote***

Be aware that there are vicious cases in Rails development mode. In order to gain speed, the strict minimum is loaded. Then Rails looks for classes definitions when needed.

But this sometimes fails big time example, when you have say `::User` already loaded, and then look for `::Admin::User`. Rails would not look for it, it will think `::User` does the trick.

This can be solved using `require_dependency` statements in your code. Speed has a cost :)

Comment: cool :) the most confusing is when you encounter issues like the one described in my sidenotes

Comment: interesting, i think your sidenote clears up the issue I was having [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29849501/object-const-get-and-rails-cutting-off-parent-module-names)

Comment: @dax cool to read :) I have had so many ahah and err moments due to this lazy loading

Answer (score 5):

I would rather suggest don't write `ApplicationController` in namespace, I would suggest to follow following

Note: If you are building professional api's it always good to have `Api::V1::BaseController` inheriting from `ActionController::Base`, though I am giving solution to your specific case

Ref this post: [Implementing Rails APIs like a professional](http://blog.joshsoftware.com/2014/05/08/implementing-rails-apis-like-a-professional/)

1) Define application controller in usual way in  app/controllers/application_controller.rb as

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
end
```

2) Define base api controller namely Api::V1::BaseController in app/controllers/api/v1/base_controller.rb which will inherit from `ApplicationController` (your case) like

```
class Api::V1::BaseController < ApplicationController
end
```

3) Define your api controllers like `Api::V1::UsersController` in  app/controllers/api/v1/users_controller.rb which will inherit from Api::V1::BaseController

```
class Api::V1::UsersController < Api::V1::BaseController
end
```

4) Add all subsequent controllers like `Api::V1::UsersController` (step 3)

Then routing will contain namespaces routing in config/routes.rb

```
namespace :api do
  namespace :v1 do
    resources :users do 
      #user routes goes here 
    end
    # any new resource routing goes here 
    # resources :new_resource do 
    # end
  end
end
```

Comment: Even though this didn't directly answer my question, it gave me more of a broad design for the API choice. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the guide to understand the routing:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing

I think this question is very similar to:

[Rails Controller Namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22913318/rails-controller-namespace)

And as shortage:

Rails will detect the namespace automagically by the folder. So you don't need to append it to the name:

**This blog post explains it so well:**

http://blog.makandra.com/2014/12/organizing-large-rails-projects-with-namespaces/

> Let's say we have an Invoice class and each invoice can have multiple
>   invoice items:
>
> ```
> class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
>   has_many :items
> end
>
> class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
>   belongs_to :invoice
> end
> ```
>
> Clearly Invoice is a composition of Items and an Item cannot live
>   without a containing Invoice. Other classes will probably
>   interact with Invoice and not with Item. So let's get Item out of the
>   way by nesting it into the Invoice namespace. This involves renaming
>   the class to Invoice::Item and moving the source file to
>   app/models/invoice/item.rb:
>
> ```
>  class Invoice::Item < ActiveRecord::Base
>    belongs_to :invoice
>  end
> ```

Same is applied to controllers and views.