# Rspec controller spec on namespaced controller finds the global controller with same name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

I have a weird issue when creating a controller spec for a namespaced controller when there also is a global controller with the same name.

The controller names are `HomeController` and `Backend::HomeController`.

Note that **I have not yet created** the file `app/controllers/backend/home_controller.rb`, only the global controller exists `app/controllers/home_controller.rb`

Therefore I expect the test to explode with errors, but it does not. It passes, all green and happy.

My spec looks like this

```
#spec/controllers/backend/home_controller_spec.rb
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Backend::HomeController, type: :controller do
  before do
    user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
    allow(controller).to receive(:authenticate_user!).and_return(true)
    allow(controller).to receive(:current_user).and_return(user)
  end
  describe "GET #index" do
    it "returns http success" do
      get :index
      expect(response).to have_http_status(:success)
    end
  end

end
```

However if I change the name in my global `HomeController` to something else, e.g `NotMyHomeController` the test fails with errors saying

```
Unable to autoload constant HomeController, expected app/controllers/home_controller.rb to define it
```

Which makes me suspect that Rspec doesn't bother with the "Backend" part in the `Rspec.describe` function.

Am I doing something wrong or am I missing some other vital part? IMHO, this spec shouldn't pass (to paraphrase Gandalf).

I'm using Rails 4.2.6, Rspec-Rails 3.4.2

**Update**

As Max pointed out, this is probably not at Rspec issue but instead something with Rails autoloading.

However i tried just typing

```
Backend::HomeController
```

In the Rails console, but there I get the expected error

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Backend::HomeController
```

And [according to the Rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html#autoloading-availability), both the console and the test suite autoloads. However I think I'm on the right track here.

Comment: I'm guessing that its the Rails autoloader doing something screwy - it works by monkeypatching `Object.const_missing` which would have normally just raised `NameError: uninitialized constant Backend::HomeController`. It has very little to with RSpec.

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up for me. Do you have any suggestions on how to investigate the Rails Autoloader further?

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html

Comment: You might want to try and see what happens if you define it as absolute rather than relative: `RSpec.describe ::Backend::HomeController`

Comment: Thank you for the tip, unfortunately using the absolute name didn't help, still the same problem and error message if I change the name of the global HomeController

Comment: Have you changed `config.autoload_paths`?

Comment: No, it's a clean rails installation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had this same problem before - you can read about the whole issue here:

[Object.const_get and Rails - cutting off parent module names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29849501/object-const-get-and-rails-cutting-off-parent-module-names)

but the meat of the answer comes from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29920332/2128691) answer from user Apneadiving:

> Be aware that there are vicious cases in Rails development mode. In order to gain speed, the strict minimum is loaded. Then Rails looks for classes definitions when needed.
>
> But this sometimes fails big time example, when you have say `::User` already loaded, and then look for `::Admin::User`. Rails would not look for it, it will think `::User` does the trick.
>
> This can be solved using `require_dependency` statements in your code.

Comment: Thank you! I ended up adding `require_dependency "#{::Rails.root}/app/controllers/backend/home_controller` in the top of my spec and it solved the problem