Rails - Named route not working in controller spec
In my routes.rb file I had this route:
resources :profiles

In my controller specs I had thus paths such as:
profiles_path
new_profile_path 

etc.
Now I had to move this inside a namespace. The new route is then:
  namespace :admin do
    resources :profiles
  end

Then I started using it as follows:
admin_profiles_path

This path works fine in my feature specs. But the problem is that when I use this in my controller specs, I'm getting the following error:
 ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
   No route matches {:action=>"/admin/profiles", :controller=>"profiles", :dir=>"asc", :order=>"name"}

When I try to check my routes for this controller however, I get the proper route:
admin_profiles GET    /admin/profiles(.:format)                admin/profiles#index

This is my controller test:
RSpec.describe Admin::ProfilesController, type: :controller do
  render_views

  describe 'GET #index' do
    before do
      user = create(:user)
      sign_in user, scope: :user
    end

    it 'sorts by profile name by default' do
      profile_a = create(:profile, name: 'A name')
      profile_b = create(:profile, name: 'B name')
      profile_c = create(:profile, name: 'C name')

      get admin_profiles_path
      
      #some expects

    end
end

And this is my action:
module Admin
  class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authenticate_user!
    load_and_authorize_resource

    def index
      if params[:search_text].present?
        @profiles = Profile.search(params[:search_text])
      else
        @profiles = Profile.all
      end
    end
  end
end

Why is it pointing to a profiles action and not an index one. And what am I doing wrong?

Maybe try require_dependency?   See this Post.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36319878/rspec-controller-spec-on-namespaced-controller-finds-the-global-controller-with

When running rails routes then this line
admin_profiles GET    /admin/profiles(.:format)    admin/profiles#index
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

tells you that the name of the route changed because you name spaced it with admin.
Instead of profiles_path (or new_profile_path), you now have to use admin_profiles_path (or new_admin_profile_path).
And will route the request following Ruby on Rails conventions to the index method of a Admin::ProfilesController.

Thank you for the answer. I upvoted :D
I had something wrong written in my question however. I edited completely to make it clearer

When changing the config/routes.rb (or any other file in config/... or lib/...) then you need to restart your Rails server. From the error message, it feels like the server wasn't restarted after changing the file.

Didnt do the trick sadly

Would you mind sharing that spec and the controller?

Done @spickermann

In the controller spec, you should be able to just call get :index, because controller specs do not run thought the whole middleware stack and do not use routing.

Thank you so much!! @spickermann
Problem solved for me

@spickermann that comment should be your actual answer. However the real answer is to not use controller specs.

Do not use controller specs.
Controller specs are just a wrapper around ActionController::TestCase which is deprechiated and it's use is strongly discouraged outside of legacy apps. The reason you can't use get admin_profiles_path is because the test helper methods for controller specs do not send real HTTP requests. Instead they call the method directly on a instance of the controller which is fed a faked request. This is an extremely flawed process as it skips the middleware and routes.
If you look at the error message it's actually telling you what's wrong:
ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
   No route matches {:action=>"/admin/profiles", :controller=>"profiles", :dir=>"asc", :order=>"name"}

That's because the action is index not /admin/profiles which is not a valid method name.
What controller tests actually use the route for is just filling in blanks in the faked request so it just tries to find something vaguely matching the combination of HTTP verb, controller, and action - it doesn't actually care about the path. This is a horrible idea and one reason why controller specs are so bug prone.
Controller tests have been deprechiated for almost a decade now. So there is no excuse for one unless it's an extremely old legacy app.
Instead the answer is to use a request or feature/system spec.
RSpec.describe 'Admin Profiles', type: :request do
  describe 'GET /admin_profiles' do
    # List your test dependencies first
    let(:user) { create(:user) }
    let!(:profiles) { create_list(:profile, 3) }
    # Set the stage
    before do
      sign_in user, scope: :user
    end

    it 'sorts by profile name by default' do
      get admin_profiles_path
      # ...
    end
  end
end


Thank you very much @max as always for your thorough answers. Here's a question however. Im using Controller specs based on the book Testing Rails and a interview I heard by DHH in which both opinions state that since feature specs are slow, they should only include the happy scenarios. Controller specs we use them for other scenarios since they dont load the view through the browser but use a DOM object which is much faster.
Please tell me your thoughts on this

That's just plain wrong/outdated. The Rails team did a ton of work on making integration tests faster so that argument is dead in the water. Even if they were slower it's well worth the acuity of having your test actually run through the entire stack instead of garbage tests that just give you a false sense of security.

Request specs also do not use a browser. You're writing expectations about the "raw" response from the server. Neither do feature specs unless you actually configure it to use a headless browser like Selenium or Chrome. By default Capybara just uses Nokogiri to parse and traverse the page but it doesn't actually work like a real browser.

If the book you're referring to is the one from Throughtbot it's from 2014 based on that they are using RSpec-Rails 3.0. While the core tenants might still be relevant the approach is not.
